# What is the fastest way to extract given rows and columns from a Numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, numpy, scipy

I have a large (approx. 14,000 x 14,000) square matrix represented as a Numpy `ndarray`. I wish to extract a large number of rows and columns--the indices of which I know in advance, though it will in fact be all rows and columns that are not all-zero--to get a new square matrix (approx 10,000 x 10,000).

The fastest way I have found to do this is:

```
> timeit A[np.ix_(indices, indices)]
1 loops, best of 3: 6.19 s per loop
```

However, this is much slower than the time it takes to do matrix multiplication:

```
> timeit np.multiply(A, A)
1 loops, best of 3: 982 ms per loop
```

This seems strange, since both the row/column extraction and matrix multiplication need to allocate a new array (which will be even larger for the result of the matrix multiplication than for the extraction), but matrix multiplication also needs to perform additional computation.

Thus, the question: is there a more efficient way to perform the extraction, in particular, that is at least as fast as matrix multiplication?

Comment: I suspect the reason matrix multiplication is fast is because it uses all the elements of the array in a strictly regular way, and has been optimized to do so.  If you have to pass in arbitrary indices (i.e., not a rectangular slice), you're not going to get max speed.

Comment: `np.multiply(A, A)` is *elementwise* multiplication.  Use `np.dot(A, A)` for matrix multiplication.

Comment: @seberg, can you elaborate? When I try `A[np.ix_(indices, indices)]` using the latest numpy 1.9 release candidate, I get the error `ValueError: Cross index must be 1 dimensional`.

Comment: It would help if you provided a working program doing what you want with random data.  I once found that np.take() was faster than indexing with [] but I'm not sure if it will matter in your case.  Try it anyway: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Yes, something like `r = A.take(indices, axis=0).take(indices, axis=1)` is faster than indexing with `[]` (using numpy 1.8.2).

Comment: Do you want me to debug your `np.ix_` call, because the new numpy complains about something that was probably funny in the first place?

Comment: The `np.ix_` call worked fine using a different NumPy 1.9 beta, so I assume there's just a bug in the version we were using.

Although the switch to NumPy 1.9 helped, it didn't give us as much of a performance boost as we really wanted. We've ended up implementing this section in Fortran and calling with [f2py](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/).

Comment: @jveldridge please raise a performance bug on numpy

Answer (score 1):

If I try to reproduce your problem, I don't see such a drastic effect. I notice that depending on how many indices you choose, the indexing can even be faster than the multiplication.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
Out[1]: '1.9.0'
>>> N = 14000
>>> A = np.random.random(size=[N, N])

>>> indices = np.sort(np.random.choice(np.arange(N), 0.9*N, replace=False))
>>> timeit A[np.ix_(indices, indices)]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.02 s per loop
>>> timeit A.take(indices, axis=0).take(indices, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.37 s per loop
>>> timeit np.multiply(A,A)
1 loops, best of 3: 748 ms per loop

>>> indices = np.sort(np.random.choice(np.arange(N), 0.7*N, replace=False))
>>> timeit A[np.ix_(indices, indices)]
1 loops, best of 3: 633 ms per loop
>>> timeit A.take(indices, axis=0).take(indices, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 946 ms per loop
>>> timeit np.multiply(A,A)
1 loops, best of 3: 728 ms per loop
```